# What's the best system integration approach?

Tags: software-design, system-integration

I want to actually know how big systems like Google, Yahoo and... using system integration to integrate their software (Google Plus, Google Video, Google shop and ...)
For example at the first time I just Login to my Google account and in all other software I have my account and I don't need to create or Login to other systems separately.

In our company we have many software like Accounting, Call Center etc. and we want to integrate our software to have a dashboard and single signing system for all software.

What's the best apprach for system integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement SSO (single sign on) for all the apps.
In this case your all the apps will change their login mechanisms respectively.Every thing will be taken care by a new application which will manage the stuff for all your apps.
See this for more details.[Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)

Comment: I think he was asking about how to implement SSO...

Comment: Correct. I need SSO implementation also but as I said before, I need an integration between softwares to create a dashboard from all other softwares (For example iGoogle dashboard and other Google Plus, Google video, Google reader and ...)